# encryption not working in ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, encryption

I always use encrypt and decrytp in codeigniter. Now when i am trying to login using ajax decrypt not working for me. My coding is as below

```
<?php
public function CheckLogin(){
        $this->input->post('password');
        $password = $this->encrypt->decode($this->input->post('password'));
        if($this->input->post('profile') == 'distributer'){
                $Response = $this->db->get_where($this->db->dbprefix."distsributer_account",array('username'=>$this->input->post('username'),'password'=>$password,'status'=>'Y'))->result();
        }
        if($this->input->post('profile') == 'retailer'){
                $Response = $this->db->get_where($this->db->dbprefix."Sefnder",array('Username'=>$this->input->post('username'),'Password'=>$password,'status'=>'Y'))->result();
        }
}
?>
```

*when i check the console giving the wrong table name password show 0 this means the `$this->encrypt->decode($this->input->post('password'))` not working for me.*

i already checked the value of $this->input->post('password') is working fine

my returned sql query is this

```
SELECT * FROM `flip_distsributer_account`
WHERE `username` = 'Asht@160921'
AND `password` =0
AND `status` = 'Y'
```

Comment: did you load the encrypt library?

Comment: i have load the encrypt library. i am facing this type of issue when i run this code through ajax

Comment: Is CSRF protection used?

Comment: You say you're having trouble with "*Ajax*-Login", but you don't show any JavaScript code. How is the password encrypted? You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Answer (score 0):

You should search with username and match the password after decrypt the saved password.

```
<?php
public function CheckLogin(){
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        if($this->input->post('profile') == 'distributer'){
            $Response = $this->db->get_where($this->db->dbprefix."distsributer_account",array('username'=>$this->input->post('username'),'status'=>'Y'))->row_array();
            if($this->encrypt->decode($Response['password']) == $password)           {
            echo "Password is equal";
         }
        }
        if($this->input->post('profile') == 'retailer'){
                $Response = $this->db->get_where($this->db->dbprefix."Sefnder",array('Username'=>$this->input->post('username'),'status'=>'Y'))->result();
        }
}
```